# como puedo simplificar la utilización de muchos if?

Tags: python

quero consultarles si existe una manera de simplificar este código y no usar tantos `Elif` o `if`. cada `Elif`, realizara una acción la cual no incluyo en el código ya que no viene al caso.
muchas gracias

```
modif=int(input("ingrese numero segun lo que quiere modificar:"))
if modif==1: 
         
elif modif==2:
         
elif modif==3:
                   
elif modif==4:
                                
elif modif==5:

elif modif==6:
```

Answer (score 3):

Realmente si para cada posible valor de `modif` tienes que hacer una cosa diferente, la secuencia de `elif` es lo correcto y aunque puede haber otras formas de escribirlo, no vas a ganar mucho en cuanto a número de líneas y sí puedes perder en claridad. Yo dejaría los `elif`.

No obstante, por si quieres ver las otras alternativas:

### Uso de diccionario de funciones

Puedes escribir en funciones separadas las acciones a realizar en cada caso:

```
def caso1():
  # Acciones para el caso 1

def caso2():
  # Acciones para el caso 2

# etc

def caso_default():
  # Acciones para el caso por defecto
```

y preparar un diccionario en el que las claves sean los posibles valores de `modif` y los valores sean esas funciones:

```
casos = { 1: caso1, 2: caso2,  ...etc }
```

Una vez has hecho todo ese trabajo, la secuencia de `if...elif` se reduce a:

```
modif = int(input("ingrese numero segun lo que quiere modificar:"))
funcion = casos.get(modif, caso_default)
funcion()
```

La función `.get()` extraerá del diccionario la función correspondiente, según el valor de la clave `modif`. Si la clave no estuviera en el diccionario retornaría entonces `caso_default`. Seguidamente llamas a esa función.

### Uso de *structural pattern matching*

Esto es una característica nueva de Python, disponible sólo a partir de Python 3.10. Aunque puede usarse simplemente como un `switch()` de otros lenguajes, realmente es muchísimo más potente y sirve para muchas más cosas, pero en este caso se usaría así:

```
modif = int(input("ingrese numero segun lo que quiere modificar:"))

match modif:
  case 1:
      # acciones para este caso
  case 2:
      # acciones para este caso

  # ... etc

  case _:
      # acciones para el caso default
```

Como ves, no has ganado mucho en cuanto a escribir menos. Y es que realmente no creo que se pueda escribir menos que usando `if/elif`.

Answer (score 2):

La manera más simple de lograr lo pedido es usando un diccionario, donde la llave es el valor y el contenido es el código a ejecutar. Este código está empaquetado en una *función* o *lambda*.

Desarrollemos un pequeño ejemplo: una aplicación que lea las teclas I,J,K,M para "mover" el cursor por una matriz. En cada iteración el usuario ingresa una tecla y el programa debe calcular e imprimir la nueva posición:

La posición la representamos por una lista [x, y], con las coordenadas horizontal y vertical del cursor.

```
>I
[0, 1]
>I
[0, 2]
>K
[1, 2]
```

Todas las funciones en el diccionario deben tener la misma *firma*, es decir, el mismo tipo y número de parámetros, y producir el mismo tipo de retorno.

Las cuatro funciones que necesitamos reciben la posición como parámetro, y la modifican:

```
def flecha_arriba(pos):
    pos[1] += 1
    
def flecha_abajo(pos):
    pos[1] -= 1
    
def flecha_izquierda(pos):
    pos[0] -= 1
    
def flecha_derecha(pos):
    pos[0] += 1
```

En el diccionario `acciones` asociamos la tecla con la acción. Fijate que se escribe el **nombre** de la función, **no** una llamada; por eso no van los paréntesis.

```
acciones = {"I": flecha_arriba,
            "M": flecha_abajo,
            "J": flecha_izquierda,
            "K": flecha_derecha
            }
```

Aqui tenemos la posición del cursor.

```
posicion = [0,0]
```

Con esto, el cuerpo de la función se reduce a leer la tecla, validarla y ejecutar la acción asociada.

Una tecla es válida si el diccionario la tiene como llave.

Para ejecutar la acción asociada a la tecla ("I", por ejemplo), tomamos la función almacenada y la llamamos (ahora si se ponen los paréntesis). Luego imprimimos la nueva posición.

```
while True:
    flecha = input('>')
    if flecha in acciones:
        acciones[flecha](posicion)
        print(posicion)
```

#### Demo

```
def flecha_arriba(pos):
    pos[1] += 1
    
def flecha_abajo(pos):
    pos[1] -= 1
    
def flecha_izquierda(pos):
    pos[0] -= 1
    
def flecha_derecha(pos):
    pos[0] += 1
    
acciones = {"I": flecha_arriba,
            "M": flecha_abajo,
            "J": flecha_izquierda,
            "K": flecha_derecha
            }

posicion = [0,0]
while True:
    flecha = input('>')
    if flecha in acciones:
        acciones[flecha](posicion)
        print(posicion)
```

y produce:

```
>I
[0, 1]
>J
[-1, 1]
>K
[0, 1]
>M
[0, 0]
>
```

Answer (score 2):

Estas son las formas que YO conozco para ahorrarme elifs. No se si son las mejores ni si las usan todos, pero al menos sirve.

#### 1: Diccionarios

Si quieres simplemente obtener un valor a partir de otro sin ningún proceso de por medio, por ejemplo:

```
modif=input("ingrese numero segun lo que quiere modificar:")

if modif=="hola": 
    resultado = "uno"  
elif modif=="adios":
    resultado = "dos"
elif modif=="mundo":
    resultado = "tres"

print(resultado)
```

Puedes pasarlo a diccionario así:

```
modif=input("ingrese numero segun lo que quiere modificar:")

condiciones = {"hola":"uno",
               "adios":"dos",
               "mundo":"tres"}
print(condiciones[modif])
```

Entre corchetes puedes colocar el contenido de la variable modif y Python se encargará de devolverte el valor relacionado. Lo que está a la izquierda del : se llama clave.

Si quieres imitar el comportamiento de un else puedes usar el método get de los diccionarios, que aceptan de primer argumento la clave y de segundo argumento el valor que se va a devolver si la clave no está en el diccionario.

```
print(condiciones.get(modif, "No se encontró el valor"))
```

Si en lugar de guardar un valor quieres ejecutar código, tendrás que colocar de valor una función (sin los parentesis a la derecha, lo que queremos es guardar la función en sí, no ejecutarla).

```
modif=input("ingrese numero segun lo que quiere modificar:")

def accion1():
    print("uno")
def accion2():
    print("dos")
def accion3():
    print("tres")
def accion_else():
    print("No se encontró el valor")
    

condiciones = {"hola":accion1,
               "adios":accion2,
               "mundo":accion3}

# aquí colocamos los parentesis para llamar a la función que vaya a devolver get.
condiciones.get(modif, accion_else)()
```

**Desventajas**

- Todos los "elifs" se ejecutan, por lo que si haces esto {hola:funcion()}, función será llamada y se colocará el resultado de dicha función como valor (lo que está a la derecha del :) del diccionario.
- Si quieres "guardar codigo" en el diccionario, deberás escribir dicho código en una función y poner de valor dicha función. Si este es tu caso, te recomiendo el tercer método que te ofrezco, que es más limpio.

#### 2: Secuencias (ejemplo: tupla, cadena, etc.)

Si lo que haces es trabajar con números, en lugar de usar un diccionario, puedes usar secuencias. Sus ítems empiezan contando de 0 e incrementan uno en uno.

Un ejemplo es como esto aplica a tu caso usando tuplas:

```
modif=int(input("ingrese numero según lo que quiere modificar:"))

tupla = ("uno", "dos", "tres")

print(tupla[modif-1])
```

U obteniendo una letra de una cadena:

```
modif=int(input("ingrese numero segun lo que quiere modificar:"))

cadena = "abc"

print(cadena[modif-1])
```

Si quieres ejecutar código con esto tienes que hacer funciones y que cada función sea un ítem de la tupla. Así para la tupla `(accion1, accion2, accion3)` el elemento 0 va a ser accion1, el 1 va a ser accion2 y así sucesivamente.
Aquí te presento un ejemplo:

```
modif=int(input("ingrese numero segun lo que quiere modificar:"))

def accion1():
    print("a")

def accion2():
    print("b")

def accion3():
    print("c")

tupla = (accion1, accion2, accion3)

tupla[modif-1]()
```

Para incluir un "else", podrías ver si el índice es menor al largo de la secuencia y si eso es cierto usar la "forma normal", mientras que si esta condición no se cumple, ejecutar lo que quieras ejecutar.
Lo entenderás mucho mejor viéndolo en código:

```
modif=int(input("ingrese numero segun lo que quiere modificar:"))

def visit_1():
    print("metodo1")
def visit_2():
    print("metodo2")
def visit_3():
    print("metodo3")

tupla = (visit_1, visit_2, visit_3)
indice = modif-1

if(indice < len(tupla)):
    tupla[indice]()
else:
    print("No se encontró")
```

**desventajas**

- Incluye las desventajas del diccionario.
- Solo puedes relacionar el contenido de la secuencia con números.
- No puedes hacer un salto. Es decir, NO puedes tener algo como "a esta en 1 y b está en 3", cosa que sí es posible en los diccionarios.
- Implementar un "else" es más complejo.

#### 3: Con POO

Puedes crear una clase y crear cada método, luego ir llamando cada uno de los métodos dependiendo del contenido de la variable modif. La función getattr acepta de primer argumento un objeto y de segundo argumento el atributo que queremos obtener de dicho objeto.

```
modif=int(input("ingrese numero según lo que quiere modificar:"))

class Metodos:
    def visit_1():
        print("metodo1")
    def visit_2():
        print("metodo2")
    def visit_3():
        print("metodo3")

# Le agrego el prefijo visit_ a lo que ingresó el usuario.
getattr(Metodos, f"visit_{modif}")()
```

Cada método de clase tiene un prefijo constante (visit_ en este caso) para evitar que el usuario pueda llamar a métodos que no debería llamar, como `"__init__"`. Recomiendo que tengas este tipo de prefijos para evitar que el usuario haga estragos en tu programa.

También podemos juntar esto con alguna de las otras dos formas para quitar el limite que tiene la función al nombrarla (el nombre de la función no puede incluir espacios ni símbolos por ejemplo).

```
modif=input("ingrese numero segun lo que quiere modificar:")

class Metodos:
    def visit_1():
        print("metodo1")
    def visit_2():
        print("metodo2")
    def visit_3():
        print("metodo3")

convertidor_nombres = {"soy una oracion":"1",
                       "soy otra oracion":"2"}

getattr(Metodos, f"visit_{convertidor_nombres[modif]}")()
```

getattr acepta un tercer argumento, que es lo que devolverá dicha función si el atributo no se encuentra. Lo podemos usar para que getattr devuelva una función especifica en caso de que el atributo buscado no exista. Está función será ejecutada como si fuera un else.

```
modif=input("ingrese numero segun lo que quiere modificar:")

class Metodos:
    def visit_1():
        print("metodo1")
    def visit_2():
        print("metodo2")
    def visit_3():
        print("metodo3")
    def visit_else():
        print("Esta oracion no está registrada")

metodo = f"visit_{modif}"

getattr(Metodos, metodo, Metodos.visit_else)()
```

Si estás usando esta forma en combinación con otra forma, deberás devolver la función que actuará como el else allí, NO en el getattr. En caso contrario, ocurrirá un error.

```
modif=input("ingrese numero segun lo que quiere modificar:")

class Metodos:
    def visit_1():
        print("metodo1")
    def visit_2():
        print("metodo2")
    def visit_3():
        print("metodo3")
    def visit_else():
        print("Esta oracion no está registrada")

convertidor_nombres = {"soy una oracion":"1",
                       "soy otra oracion":"2"}
metodo = f"visit_{convertidor_nombres.get(modif, 'else')}"

getattr(Metodos, metodo)()
```

**Desventajas**

- Es innecesariamente complejo si lo único que buscas es obtener un valor a partir de otro sin ningún proceso de por medio.
- Si quieres relacionar una función con algo que no sea su propio nombre, vas a tener que usar alguna de las otras formas de reemplazar los elifs.

---

#### Conclusión

Como podrás ver, hay varias formas de evitar el uso de elifs y a la hora de evaluar la condición ahorrarte varias líneas. Y las formas con diccionarios (sobre todo) y secuencias son útiles cuando quieres obtener un valor a partir de otro sin ningún proceso de por medio. Pero cuando quieras que haya un proceso de por medio, vas a tener un código más complejo y que no te ahorra muchas líneas en el programa en general.

La verdad es que todo depende del caso en el que estes. A veces te convendrá más el uso de elifs, otras veces el de diccionarios, y así. Solo tienes que analizar el caso en el que te encuentres y sabrás que forma usar.

#### Para finalizar

Entiendo que esta respuesta es muy larga, me llevó mucho escribirla. Así que cualquier cosa que no entiendas dime en los comentarios y te responderé con gusto c: